# Failing to deploy to Win10 VM via MDT Error 5616

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10, wds, mdt

I'm testing a windows 10 deployment through MDT and WDS. I've been running through the following MS Documentation and I've reach the point where I'm booting the VM from the iso that has been created. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/prepare-for-windows-deployment-with-mdt. However, the deployment fails and I've dug out the following error message from the BDD log file.

```
    <![LOG[  Console > Failure when attempting to copy boot files.]LOG]!><time="14:29:19.000+000" date="08-25-2020" component="ztiRunCommandHidden" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ztiRunCommandHidden">
<![LOG[Return code from command = 15299]LOG]!><time="14:29:19.000+000" date="08-25-2020" component="ztiRunCommandHidden" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ztiRunCommandHidden">
<![LOG[Command has returned: 15299]LOG]!><time="14:29:19.000+000" date="08-25-2020" component="LTIApply" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTIApply">
<![LOG[FAILURE ( 5616 ): 15299: Verify BCDBootEx]LOG]!><time="14:29:19.000+000" date="08-25-2020" component="LTIApply" context="" type="3" thread="" file="LTIApply">
```

When troubleshooting I came across the following article about there being a hotfix for the version of MDT I'm using. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4564442/windows-10-deployments-fail-with-microsoft-deployment-toolkit. I copied in the replacement files as instructed, checked that the WDS server was fully patched, and rebooted the server. But I'm still having issues.

The error message that I'm getting on the test VM is as follows.

[image]

WDS Server is running Windows Server 2016 Standard
MDT Version is 6.3.8456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this one by adding the following script to the task schedule within MDT. https://github.com/DeploymentResearch/DRFiles/blob/master/Scripts/FixUEFIDetection.wsf.

Thanks to this video on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4Xfen6Slrk